# Only first If statement runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do some basic form validation to make sure these 3 fields have a value entered when the submit button is clicked but only the first if {} statement runs and skips the other two. If I reorder the if statements, again only the first one runs. I know javascript will exit the first true condition for a if/else statement but I thought separate if statements would all run. The $("#vld_xxx").show() stuff is just making a div visible to show the user which fields are missing a value.

```
         function validateForm() {
             let Date_Issue_Began_Value = $("#MainContent_txtDate_Issue_Began").val();
             let Date_Issue_Ended_Value = $("#MainContent_txtDate_Issue_Ended").val();
             let Resolution_Value = $("#MainContent_txtResolution").val();                 

             if (Date_Issue_Began_Value.length == "") {
                 $("#vld_Date_Issue_Began").show();
                 Date_Issue_BeganError = false;
                 return false;
             }

             if (Date_Issue_Ended_Value.length == "") {                     
                 $("#vld_Date_Issue_Ended").show();
                 Date_Issue_EndedError = false;
                 return false;
             }                 

             if (Resolution_Value.length == "") {
                 $("#vld_Resolution").show();
                 ResolutionError = false;
                 return false;
             }                             
         }           


         // Submit button
         $("#MainContent_btnSubmit").click(function () {
             //alert('click');
             validateForm();                 
             if (
                 Date_Issue_BeganError == true &&
                 Date_Issue_EndedError == true &&
                 ResolutionError == true                      
             ) {
                 return true;
             } else {
                 return false;
             }
         });
```

Comment: Every one of your `if` blocks contains a `return`, so whichever one runs first will *return*.  Is that not what you intended?

Comment: the `return false` in each if ends the function, so if the first condition is true (Date_Issue_Began_Value.length == ""), the functions ends at the first statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to return, don't use a `return` statement.  You can return *after* the `if` blocks.  For example:

```
let result = true;

if (Date_Issue_Began_Value.length == "") {
  $("#vld_Date_Issue_Began").show();
  Date_Issue_BeganError = false;
  result = false;
}

if (Date_Issue_Ended_Value.length == "") {                     
  $("#vld_Date_Issue_Ended").show();
  Date_Issue_EndedError = false;
  result = false;
}                 

if (Resolution_Value.length == "") {
  $("#vld_Resolution").show();
  ResolutionError = false;
  result = false;
}

return result;
```

---

As another user [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78067961/javascript-only-first-if-statement-runs#comment137627897_78067998), you're also not *using* the returned value anyway.  You're passing messages with global variables, which is generally a bad idea and gets unmaintainable fast.  If the result of the function is what you need, just use the result of the function:

```
$("#MainContent_btnSubmit").click(function () {
  return validateForm();                 
});
```

Unless you need them for anything else, you can probably remove those global variables entirely.

---

[Also...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78067961/only-first-if-statement-runs#comment137627997_78067998) this is a *very strange* way to test for `0`:

```
if (Date_Issue_Began_Value.length == "")
```

If you want to check if the `length` is `0`, check if the `length` is `0`:

```
if (Date_Issue_Began_Value.length == 0)
```

You may even want to get in the habit of using stricter equality:

```
if (Date_Issue_Began_Value.length === 0)
```

What you have technically *does* work, but why rely on strange habits?  That's just bugs waiting to happen.

Comment: Agreed, however if you look at the click handler, there is nothing done with this return. I want to note also that the handler can be simplified to 'return validateForm()'.

Comment: Won't comparing a number to a string end up false always, anyway?? I think what OP wanted was actually something like `if (Date_Issue_Began_Value.trim() === "") {` [...] or `if (Date_Issue_Began_Value.length === 0) {` [...].

Comment: @Peybro: Good catch, I didn't even look at the comparison itself.  What the OP has technically *does* work, but it's certainly a very strange way to test for `0`...